# calculating the average of marks from the beginning to this record

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table named test with the below structure like this

```
id mark join_id
1  5    1
2  4    1
3  9    1
4  5    2 
5  7    2
6  12   2
```

i want to write a query that can get me the average of the marks from the beginning record to this record  with the desired result as below

```
id mark join_id   avg_of_previous_marks
1  5    1         5      
2  4    1         4.5
3  9    1         6
4  5    2         5.75
5  7    2         6
6  12   2         7
```

i wrote this query but it doesn't seem to work correctly

```
SELECT test.id, test.mark, test.join_id,  test_avg.avg_of_previous_marks FROM test
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, join_id, AVG(mark) as avg_of_previous_marks FROM test GROUP BY 
join_id) test_avg 
ON test_avg.join_id = test.join_id AND test_avg.id <= test.id
```

and it gives this resault

```
id mark join_id   avg_of_previous_marks
1  5    1         6      
2  4    1         6
3  9    1         6
4  5    2         8
5  7    2         8
6  12   2         8
```

Comment: Its just a running total - something like this: select avg(mark) over (order by id) from test_avg ;

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple running total that you need.

```
select id,mark,join_id, avg(mark) over (order by id) avg_of_previous_marks from test_avg ;
```

fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf95fdfcf207430c544dd2457354b437)